# GATT Server not showing all the services after bonding

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I have gatt server running on macOS, code snippet the peripheral manager delegate:

```
//
//  BLEServer.swift
//  myapp
//
//

import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

class BLEPeripheral:NSObject,ObservableObject,CBPeripheralManagerDelegate{
    
    @Published var isSwitchedOn = false
    @Published var msg:String = ""
    var isServiceAdded = false
    
    var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager!
    let characteristic1:CBMutableCharacteristic
    let characteristic2:CBMutableCharacteristic
    let service:CBMutableService
    let peripheralQueue:DispatchQueue
    
    

    override init(){

        self.characteristic1 = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: BLEUtils.characteristicID, properties: [.write,.writeWithoutResponse], value: nil, permissions: [.writeable])
        self.characteristic2 = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: BLEUtils.characteristicID2, properties: [.read], value: "Yo guys".data(using: .utf8), permissions: [.readable])
        self.service = CBMutableService(type: BLEUtils.serviceID, primary: true)
        self.service.characteristics = [characteristic1,characteristic2]

        self.peripheralQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Peripheral Queue")
        super.init()
        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: peripheralQueue)
    }
    
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        if peripheral.state == .poweredOn{
            print("Peripheral State: ON")
            isSwitchedOn = true
            
            peripheralManager.add(self.service)
            
        }
        else{
            print("Peripheral State: OFF")
            isSwitchedOn = false
            peripheralManager.removeAllServices()
            if(peripheral.isAdvertising){
                peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
            }
            
        }
    }
    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAdd service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error{
            print("Add service failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }else{
            print("Service \(service.uuid) added!")
            let advertisingName = "BLE Connect"
            var advertisementData:[String:Any] = [:]
            advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] = advertisingName
            advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey] = [self.service.uuid]
            peripheralManager.startAdvertising(advertisementData)
        }
    }
    func peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error{
            print("Advertisement failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }else{
            print("Advertisement Started")
        }
    }
    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWrite requests: [CBATTRequest]) {
        print("Write request recieved")
        for request in requests{
            peripheralManager.respond(to: request, withResult: .success)
            guard let data = request.value else{
                return
            }
            let message = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
            msg = message
            print(message)
        }
        
    }
    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveRead request: CBATTRequest) {
        peripheralManager.respond(to: request, withResult: .success)
    }
    
    
    
}
```

A GATT client is running on android, code for GATT client callback:

```
private class GattClientCallback : BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)
            val isSuccess = status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS
            val isConnected = newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange: Client $gatt  success: $isSuccess connected: $isConnected")
            // try to send a message to the other device as a test
            if (isSuccess && isConnected) {
                viewModel.setConnectionState(true)
                // discover services
                gatt.discoverServices()
            }
            else{
                viewModel.setConnectionState(false)
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun onServicesDiscovered(discoveredGatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(discoveredGatt, status)
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered: Have gatt $discoveredGatt")
                gatt = discoveredGatt
                val service = discoveredGatt.getService(myServiceUUID1)
                if(service!=null){
                    messageCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(myCharacteristicsUUID1)
                }
            }
        }
```

Now whenever I try to connect to the gatt server (macOS) using gatt client. Request for `Pair and Connect` pops up in both the devices. If I cancel the pair request, client can connect to server and can read services and characteristics and client do not disconnect automatically. But, if I accept the pair request and pair both devices. Client connects to server but disconnect automatically after few seconds and It can't find the services which I added to the server.

I also tried to check services using nRf connect app, before bonding all the services are shown but after bonding only Generic Attribute Service is visible.
I also tried removing the paired device from both the devices. When I cancel the pairing request and restart the server and client, services are visible.

Before bonding:
[Services before bonding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgNvf.jpg)

After Bonding:
[After bonding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iERgS.jpg)

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance